# Why are my donut charts positioned outside the container when other chart types are correctly positioned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I have a bunch of charts which get drawn in the same div by the user clicking on a link (each click removes the previous svg and then draws the new one). All charts are positioned in the center of the div as expected except donut charts. Any reasons why? I've created a JS Fiddle to help illustrate this.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y63ftoc4/)

Basically, I have three functions. The generic drawChart() function which takes in the index of the button which has been clicked and contains a switch statement which picks what chart to draw. Then there is chartTwo() which is just two lines to illustrate how that chart is positioned in the center. chartOne() is a donut chart which is being positioned outside of top left corner.
Thanks for any help.

*Generic chart builder func*

```
function drawChart(int){

  var $chartarea = $('#chartarea'),
      ca_w = $chartarea.innerWidth(),
      ca_h = $chartarea.innerHeight();


  if ($chartarea.find('svg').length > 0) {
    $chartarea.find('svg').remove();
  }

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};

  var width = ca_w - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = ca_h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var g = d3.select('#chartarea').append('svg')
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
      .style('position', 'relative')
      .style('left', '0')
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('transform', 'translate('+margin.left+', '+margin.top+')');

  switch (int) {
    case 0:
      chartOne(g, width, height);
      break;
    case 1:
      chartTwo(g, width, height);
      break;
    default:
      chartOne(g, width, height);
  }

}
```

*Donut chart func*

```
function chartOne(g, width, height) {

  var data = [
    {name: "USA", value: 40},
    {name: "UK", value: 20},
    {name: "Canada", value: 30},
    {name: "Maxico", value: 10},
  ];

  var text = "";

  var thickness = 40;

  var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - thickness)
  .outerRadius(radius);

  var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .sort(null);

  g.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        let g = d3.select(this)
          .style("cursor", "pointer")
          .style("fill", "black")
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "text-group");

        g.append("text")
          .attr("class", "name-text")
          .text(d.data.name)
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .attr('dy', '-1.2em');

        g.append("text")
          .attr("class", "value-text")
          .text(d.data.value)
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .attr('dy', '.6em');
      })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .style("cursor", "none")
          .style("fill", color(this._current))
          .select(".text-group").remove();
      })
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i))
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .style("cursor", "pointer")
          .style("fill", "black");
      })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .style("cursor", "none")
          .style("fill", color(this._current));
      })
    .each(function(d, i) { this._current = i; });


  g.append('text')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dy', '.35em')
    .text(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a *translate* to adjust for the `width` and `height` can be added to `chartOne()` function:

```
g.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

Now you can add the *margins* and finish up I guess. See demo below:

```js
$(function() {

  // on load
  $('li').eq(0).addClass('active');
  drawChart(0);

  $('li').on('click', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    drawChart(index);
  });
});

function drawChart(int) {

  var $chartarea = $('#chartarea'),
    ca_w = $chartarea.innerWidth(),
    ca_h = $chartarea.innerHeight();


  if ($chartarea.find('svg').length > 0) {
    $chartarea.find('svg').remove();
  }

  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20
  };

  var width = ca_w - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = ca_h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var g = d3.select('#chartarea').append('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .style('position', 'relative')
    .style('left', '0')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

  switch (int) {
    case 0:
      chartOne(g, width, height, margin);// edited
      break;
    case 1:
      chartTwo(g, width, height);
      break;
    default:
      chartOne(g, width, height, margin);// edited
  }

}

function chartTwo(g, width, height) {
  g.append('line')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', height)
    .attr('stroke', 'grey')
    .attr('stroke-width', '10px');
  g.append('line')
    .attr('x1', width)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y2', height)
    .attr('stroke', 'grey')
    .attr('stroke-width', '10px');
}


function chartOne(g, width, height, margin) { // edited
  // ADDED THIS
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + margin.left) + "," + (height / 2 + margin.top) + ")");

  var data = [{
      name: "USA",
      value: 40
    },
    {
      name: "UK",
      value: 20
    },
    {
      name: "Canada",
      value: 30
    },
    {
      name: "Maxico",
      value: 10
    },
  ];

  var text = "";

  var thickness = 40;

  var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - thickness)
    .outerRadius(radius);

  var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
    .sort(null);

  g.selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      let g = d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "text-group");

      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "name-text")
        .text(d.data.name)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '-1.2em');

      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "value-text")
        .text(d.data.value)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '.6em');
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")
        .style("fill", color(this._current))
        .select(".text-group").remove();
    })
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', (d, i) => color(i))
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")
        .style("fill", color(this._current));
    })
    .each(function(d, i) {
      this._current = i;
    });


  g.append('text')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dy', '.35em')
    .text(text);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#chartarea {
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  background: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
  background: #60cafe
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartarea" class="charts--item"></div>

<ul>
  <li>Chart One</li>
  <li>Chart Two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pie/donut chart is positioned with a center at `[0,0]` while your x is comprised of lines with endpoints like this one:

```
.attr('x1', 0)
.attr('y1', 0)
.attr('x2', width)
.attr('y2', height)
```

Your lines start and end at the corner of the visualization, where as your pie/donut chart is centered on the corner.

The easiest way to fix this is to create a `g` to hold the pie chart that has a different transform than the `g` to hold the rest of the charts. This new `g` will have a translate of `[width/2,height/2]` and will place the center of the pie chart in the center of the visualization. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwzgdjgr/).